# How to get Total Post In a Selceted category

Tags: categories

i have a wordpress site that has around 20000 post
it gets slow at generating pagination. i have traced the problem.

```
$my_query = new WP_Query($query_string ."&posts_per_page=-1");
$total_posts = $my_query->post_count;
```

is there any other faster way to get total post on a selected category.

Answer (score 1):

I have one solution for you. 
This code will show and unordered list with the name of the category and the count of posts containded in it.

```
<ul class="myClass">
 <?php $categories = get_categories('number=100');
       foreach ($categories as $cat) {
       echo "<li>". $cat->cat_name . " Total posts: ". $cat->category_count ."</li>";
       } ?>
</ul>
```

Retrieves the 100 first categories

```
$categories = get_categories('number=100');
```

and for each of them shows `cat_name` and `category_count`

Well the result I presume you really need can now be handled in a var by  `$cat->category_count`, i.e:

```
$total_num_posts_in_your_category = $cat->category_count
```

I hope that could help you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there isn't one. The default WordPress count function does not support category posts count:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts

Answer (score 0):

you can use `get_category` :

```
 $thisCat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'),false);
$total_posts = $thisCat->count;
```

Comment: Is there really a function named `count` that does nothing than `count( $thisCat )`?

Comment: I'm not sure i get the question,  but if you're refering to the `count` php function, well that is not the case here.

Comment: My failure. Haven't seen that it gets delivered with the object.